# Navigation Bar not transparent

Tags: ios, navigationcontroller

[Apple say this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/barTintColor):

> **barTintColor**
>
> This color is made translucent by default unless you set the translucent property to NO.

**So why is my code producing an opaque navigation bar?**

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f     green:119/255.0f blue:255/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

I tried adding this just in case, but no luck.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f     green:119/255.0f blue:255/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

why don't you try setting the background color

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f     green:119/255.0f blue:255/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

The bar is translucent :)

As per your need. This will give a solid color to the navigation bar

```
NSArray *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if ([[ver objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 7) {
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}else {
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the colour then goes way, way too pale. I can't get it as dark as if I manually dragged in a navigation bar and chose a colour, with translucent checked. This doesn't seem right at all.

Comment: You can change the alpha value and get the desired result!

Comment: A translucent NavigationBar does not have full and deep colors.. If the background color of the ViewController is white, the NavigationBar will appear brighter.

Comment: Anything above 1.0 makes no difference. Sorry I feel like I must be missing something really obvious, but it just doesn't work.

filou: If I drag in a navigation bar and give it a tint, the colour is far darker than with this code.

Comment: can you explain exactly what you want to achieve? i.e. what is you background colour and what do you want your navigation bar to have?

Comment: The navigation bar will have text scrolling beneath it, but I want it to be blue in colour.

Comment: Edited the post as per your need. Now you are able to have a solid color and a translucent color. There should not be a problem with this

Answer (score 0):

Its much easier to use the "appearance" proxy in your appDelagate.m. In your didGinishLaunchingWithOptions method include:

```
[UINavigationBar appearance].translucent = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4

```
  navigationController!.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false;
```